# How to acees the exact total memory from vagrant VM

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision, vagrant-plugin, vagrant-share

Ex : here I am able to see the base memory in vagrant machine 11800
Is there any Linux or any other
command to extract this memory value it should retrive 11800

Comment: When I tried with free command it was showing total memory 11495 mb instead of 11800 waht will be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know how much memory is available during/after provisioning, when you get a shell on the machine ?

Then it would be the free command I guess : https://linuxize.com/post/free-command-in-linux/

Comment: When I tried with free command it was showing total memory 11495 mb instead of 11800 waht will be the issue? How I can get exact 11800 mb